# How to redirect to another page when selected dropdown item is changed?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have 2 dropdown lists that I'm putting on to the page as follows. I can't get either to work:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", Model.CategoryList, "Select a category to view")%>
```

and

```
<%=Html.DropDownList() For(m => m.SearchExpression) %>
```

What I need is to be able to redirect to a page when one of the items is selected and I click submit.

Can somebody please outline the steps I need to take to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% using( Html.BeginForm() ) { %>
     <%= Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.SearchExpression %>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>
```

You will have a controller with a POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo( ... )
{
    return RedirectToAction( ... );
    // OR return RedirectToRoute( ... );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your working in asp.net, you can put code in the SelectedIndexChanged event attached to the dropdown.  Within this event, you can call Reponse.Redirect(url).